# Automatic login on Angstrom Linux

Tags: linux, authentication, beagleboard, angstrom-linux

What is a clean way to obtain Angstrom Linux to boot up and open the shell without asking to log in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a nice way to achieve it. This works for me with Angstrom (on a Beagleboard xM Rev C4).

1. Make sure agetty is installed (/sbin/agetty is the standard location). It should be included in every Linux Angstrom image.
2. Create a script file in any location, for example /home/root/autologin.sh. Edit it and add the following:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   exec /bin/login -f root
   ```
3. Make it executable with the command

   ```
   chmod a+x autologin.sh
   ```
4. Edit the file /etc/inittab. Comment out (by adding a “#” at the beginning) the following line

   ```
   1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1
   ```

and add the following line:

```
    1:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -l /home/root/autologin.sh -n 38400 tty1 linux
```

Hope this helps out there.

Comment: I am running Angstrom v2012.01-core - Kernel 3.0.17+ and don't have an /etc/inittab file. Been researching this for about half an hour and haven't found a solution. I guess it's impossible for those of us who don't have an /etc/inittab file.

Comment: Hi Samuel, If you don't have the inittab this solution will not work for you. Sorry that I can't help you that much. Though, I am sure there is another equivalent file for startup automation.
If you solved this please let me know.

Answer (score 6):

This simple answer took me hours to find. For those of you who don't have /etc/inittab the following worked for me. In

```
/etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/serial-getty@ttyO2.service
```

change the line

```
ExecStart=-/sbin/getty 115200 %I
```

to

```
 ExecStart=-/sbin/getty -a USERNAME 115200 %I
```

I partially figured this out on my own from reading about getty in /etc/inittab, which led me to ExecStart on my system, and a quick google search led me to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42359/how-can-i-autologin-to-desktop-with-systemd which gave me the auto-login syntax of /sbin/getty.

Comment: Nice solution! But are you sure you don't have an inittab equivalent anywhere?
Thank you so much for sharing this!

Comment: No systems with usage of systemd have no inittab. inittab comes from sysvinit.

Comment: Next questions please provide more information about your system :-)

Comment: There is no /etc/inittab file or folder on my system. I have a BeagleBoard xM revC1. Version information that is displayed after reboot: "Angstrom v2012.01-core - Kernel 3.0.17+". Output from cat /proc/version: "Linux version 3.0.17+ (koen@dominion) (gcc version 4.5.4 20111126 (prerelease) (GCC) )".

Comment: No need to rant about liking or disliking a particular OS.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is more linux-generic.
Without a start of a getty-process you doesn't have a passwort login. Look at

```
/etc/inittab
```

starts here a *getty-process? Remove this line and restart your device.

Comment: That's what I'm looking at mainly. This is the line I have in inittab:

1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1

Comment: if you remove this line and your distribution is busybox based you should get a "Press enter for console"-like message on next restart of your angstrom based system.

Comment: I don't have an /etc/inittab file, running: Angstrom v2012.01-core - Kernel 3.0.17+.

Answer (score 0):

```
1:2345:respawn:/bin/login -f root tty1 </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1
```

change tty1 for your system configuration, ex) ttyO0, ttyS1, etc..