# Beaglebone inittab issue

Tags: linux, bash, init, beagleboard, angstrom-linux

I am developing an application in beaglebone.
I want to add start up scripts to my Beaglebone but I can not find /etc/inittab. 
I am using the image : Angstrom-Cloud9-IDE-GNOME-eglibc-ipk-v2012.05-beaglebone-2012.06.18.img.xz

I think in the previous versions of image there is /etc/initab but for the new distributions I could not find the inittab :/

I want to apply this : [Automatic login on Angstrom Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282981/automatic-login-on-angstrom-linux)
but I can not because there is no /etc/inittab.

Where is the inittab in new distributions.

When I write uname -r it gives: 
3.2.23

Regards

Comment: Auto-Login Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282981/automatic-login-on-angstrom-linux Automatically Start Application Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149477/auto-start-program-at-login-in-angstrom-on-beagleboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inittab has been replaced by systemd

This is how I did it for the serial console. You can probably adapt it easily for tty1 by replacing "serial-getty@..." by "getty@...", but I haven't tested it.

```
cp /lib/systemd/system/serial-getty@.service /etc/systemd/system/autologin@.service
rm /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/serial-getty@ttyO0.service
ln -s /etc/systemd/system/autologin@.service /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/serial-getty@ttyO0.service
```

Create the following script file in any location (/home/root/autologin.sh in my case)

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /bin/login -f root
```

Make it executable

```
chmod a+x autologin.sh
```

Edit /etc/systemd/system/autologin@.service and update the ExecStart command by adding the -n (Do not prompt the user for a login name) and -l (Invoke the specified login_program instead of /bin/login) options.

```
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -n -l /home/root/autologin.sh -s %I 115200
```