# Auto-Start Program at Login in Angstrom on BeagleBoard

Tags: linux, beagleboard, autostart, angstrom-linux

How do I start an application automatically after login? I have tried the following:

1. Editing `/etc/inittab` but I don't have an `/etc/inittab` file, it
   looks like my system uses systemd.
2. Starting my application by adding it to the script `/etc/rc.local`.
3. Adding a script in `/etc/init.d` and a symlink to the script in
   `/etc/rc5.d/S51script_name`.
4. Calling my script from `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`.
5. Adding a service to systemd but I couldn't get it to work and it
   seems more complicated than it should be for my purposes.

I am running Angstrom v2012.01-core - Kernel 3.0.17+ on BeagleBoard xM.

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer: The script /etc/profile is ran when the user logs in. You can add a line to start your application at the end it.