# Auto login on BeagleBone White + Angstrom 3.2

Tags: autologin, angstrom-linux, systemd

I'd like to find a way to make my BeagleBone (white) Rev A6a autologin after being powered up. I'm using Angstrom with kernel 3.2.34, which uses systemd instead of innitab.
I've already seen some topics (like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282981/automatic-login-on-angstrom-linux)) with reference to modifications on some service files (like `/etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service`), but that only helped me partly: If I power/reset my BBone while keeping it connected via USB to my computer, it autologs as expected. But, if I just power the BBone with a wallwart (without any other connections), it doesn't seem to log in. At least I believe that's what is happening, as I have a program prepared to autorun after login and it only starts on the first case (with USB on).
I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that a RF module attached to my beaglebone was being powered via USB, and this module should be activated by my test program mentioned in the question. So, when I unplugged my BBone USB cable, I was actually separating its GND from the RF Module's ground.

In short, I just had to use the same source in the entire circuit and keep the autologin configuration explained in the [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282981/automatic-login-on-angstrom-linux) I also mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your program a service and run after user instance of `systemd`.
Lets say you have a `graphical.target` in your `/usr/lib/systemd/system` then just put symlink to `../systemd-user@.target` to `/usr/lib/systemd/system/graphical.target.wants/system` named like `systemd-user@<your-user-name>.service`.
This `systemd-user@.service` should containe `ExecStart` line like `/usr/bin/systemd --user`.
Then you'll have to add your application's service-file to `/usr/lib/systemd/user`.

More info is at http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.html and http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html